# JavaScript Regex - How to check if a string only contains letters, numbers, dashes, underscores and dots

Tags: javascript, regex

everybody i want to check if a string **contains only specific type of characters** and characters are all **letters**, **numbers**, **dots**, **underscores** and **dashes**.

If the string contains other characters besides the ones i have mentioned then it should result in false value.

Here is an example on how the regex should work:

```
const regex = /regexpression/;



const string1 = "abra-ibra_cadabra.2";

// Should console log true
console.log(regex.test(string1));



const string2 = "!abra-ibra";

// Should console log false
console.log(regex.test(string2));

const string3 = "(abra)_ibra";

// Should console log false
console.log(regex.test(string3));
```

Comment: you have to come here with a least something, piece of code or detailed idea. we won't do the work for you. By the way, the example won't work (syntax errors)

Comment: try this expression `/[\w\.\-\d_]+/`

Comment: We will not do the job free for you !¡! What have you tried so far instead of just your pseudo-code `that's even not javascript code -> String without quotes ?`

Comment: @johannchopin i think he forgot to write the quote by the wrong

Comment: @Joseph: `\d` & `_` are already included in `\w`

Comment: @Toto thanks for this notice it helped, i will edit it now :)

Comment: Hi, guys i am new stack overflow and i didn't mean to be rude, next time i will come with peace of code.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the JavaScript test() Method as follow:

```js
const string1 = "abra-ibra_cadabra.2";
const string2 = "!abra-ibra";
const string3 = "(abra)_ibra";

let patt = /^(\w|\.|-)+$/;

console.log('string1:', patt.test(string1));
console.log('string2:', patt.test(string2));
console.log('string3:', patt.test(string3));
```

**Explanation:**

```
^     : asserts position at start of the string,

$     : asserts position at the end of the string,

+     : Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times,
```

**Capturing Group:**

Between parenthesis, every alternatives are separated by "|" (or) symbol:

```
(\w|\.|-)
```

> 1st Alternative:

```
\w     : matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
```

> 2nd Alternative:

```
\.     : matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
```

> 3rd Alternative:

```
-     : matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: `(\w|\.|-)+` <==> `[\w.-]+`

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the explanation